# SoundBlaster Live! Value drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sound-card

My Dell Dimension 8200 came with Windows XP and a SoundBlaster Live! Value card. I have just installed Windows 7 32-bit, but it does not recognize the card. I have tried using the original SoundBlaster installation CD and installing with each of the three options provided. Every attempt results in the Blue Screen of Death, saying something about a Pool Header (this part is beyond my skills).

I have searched the SoundBlaster Web site but find nothing later than Windows 98.

Any suggestions for what I can do, short of installing a new card?

Answer (score 1):

The short and long answers are the same here: **nothing**.

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for over one year, including using the older XP drivers from Creative, using the KXProject drivers, and even modifying drivers from other sound cards (e.g. the Audigy series).

The two main problems are that there are no drivers compatible with the sound card, Windows 7, and over 2 GB of RAM.  The only compatible drivers for the sound card and Windows 7 work with 2 GB of RAM or less, and even then, are still unstable.  The second problem is the lack of official driver support from Creative.

I know this is not the answer you want to hear, but after searching for a driver for this particular sound card from the Windows 7 Beta, I still have found *nothing*, and decided to purchase something new.  As a warning to yourself, if you do decide to continue with Creative's products, ensure that the new card is from the X-Fi series (or newer).  I found compatibility issues with the Audigy series under Windows 7, and was forced to upgrade again (after which I decided that I would not be getting another Creative sound card).